# SSRS Reporting - show "All" in parameter when the user clicks on Select All option

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2012, ssrs-tablix, rdl

I'm trying to set the parameter as "All" when the user clicks on "Select All" option in the multi-select parameter. The requirement is to not show all the selected values in the top.
Currently, I'm getting this:

[image: Comma-separated values]

This is the expected value when all are selected:

[image: Display 'All']

How to add this requirement? I have tried with adding dataset with "All" value in the table but that is only useful in case I need to display the value inside the report but I need to show it as the parameter in the place where we are selecting parameters.

Comment: Please don't post images https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551

Answer (score 0):

You can add the 'All' entry to your parameter by UNIONing it in your parameter dataset (it sounds like you have already done this), and then just interpret that in your dataset query.

So your query might then look like this.

```
SELECT * FROM myTable 
WHERE (Result IN (@myParameter) OR @myParameter = 'All')
```